# How to get all tables and number of rows in each table

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I would like to print out all tables in a database and then the number of rows for each table. Currently I can print all tables

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database = "data1"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
query = 'show tables'
#query2 = 'select count(*)'
mycursor.execute(query)

for x in mycursor:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` table, specifically the `TABLE_ROWS` column. Check the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: To be specific, `SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='data1'`